# Why does my Linux appear as 'ChromeLinux_C4EA' on my windows 10 laptop?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, windows-10

My computer is obviously named 'Skybbles', but it appears as 'ChromeLinux_C4EA' on my windows 10 laptop. To me this is very suspicious. Can anyone tell me what's going on, and how to fix?

Linux Dist: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Where exactly is it named that? Could be a few reasons, really... If you're using something like TeamViewer, it could be that you've got the Google Chrome TeamViewer app installed, thus it will show up as that. If you're running Chrome OS with Crouton (chroot environment), that would also explain it. Other than that, which distro are you using, and are you sure you've got the right device? I wouldn't be entirely shocked to find you're looking at a Chrome TV stick or something (not intended to offend, just would make more sense). You could run `hostname` to find your actual hostname.

Comment: If I hadn't read the tags for the question, I wouldn't have know what were you referring to. It is good if you specify it is related to Bluetooth. I have the same on my computer. It seems to be the default name `blueman` (Bluetooth manager) gives to the bluetooth adapter on the computer. You can change it in the Blueman config.

Comment: @Mike I'm not using a bluetooth adapter or anything external. I'm using the Dell Inspiron 2 Model 3048. That already has bluetooth built-in. And, if it works, how do i access blueman?

Comment: @XtrmJosh I don't have TeamVIewer or or ChromeOS. Did you read my question? :(

Comment: @SkyBlueDaPon3 yes I read your question, you don't state in the question body that this is about the name of the bluetooth device so I didn't know until I read Mike's comment. I'm not psychic.

Answer (score 2):

If I hadn't read the tags for the question, I wouldn't have known what you were referring to. It is good if you edit the question and specify it is related to Bluetooth. I have the same on my computer. It seems to be the default name blueman (Bluetooth manager) gives to the internal bluetooth adapter on the computer. As DK Bose said. You can run:

```
blueman-applet
```

Quoting DK Bose:

> In the window that opens, click on Adapter, Preferences and enter the name you want to see under "Friendly Name".